# ¿Cómo hacer una calculadora de porcentajes con miles en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero que la gente escriba un valor y saque los porcentajes, pero a la hora de escribir las personas, se de formato al `input` y cada 3 números se ponga el punto que indica mil.

La verdad intenté hacerlo pero no me ha dado. Quiero saber cómo lo harían ustedes y que código utilizarían.

Adjunto imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código actual:

```js
function calculaPorcentajes(numero){
  document.getElementById("porcent4").value=Math.floor(numero*4)/100;
  document.getElementById("porcent6").value=Math.floor(numero*6)/100;
  document.getElementById("porcent8").value=Math.floor(numero*8)/100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    
Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad"  onKeyUp="calculaPorcentajes(this.value)"><br><br>
4%: <input type="text" name="porcent4" id="porcent4"><br><br>
6%: <input type="text" name="porcent6" id="porcent6"><br><br>
8%: <input type="text" name="porcent8" id="porcent8">    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, ya regrese, te doy la respuesta con lujo de detalles pero antes pon el código en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: @the-breaker amigo ya te busque en facebook, y te hable, para contarte como es que estaba trabajando porque, la verdad  ando perdido.

pero quiero saber como harías esto vos?

Comment: para eso hace falta el código, subelo y lo analizamos, cuando ganes un poco mas de reputación podrás iniciar un chat desde la pagina con otros usuarios para tratar estos temas.

Comment: @the-breaker es que la verdad no tengo ni idea como comenzar a hacerlo :( pro eso mi pregunta es como se podria hacer porque no tengo ni idea, pero estoy viendo unos tutoriales, ya pongo el codigo.

Comment: @the-breaker  ya acomode el codigo de pruebas esto es lo que entiendo pero cuando tengo que ingresar la formateada de los puntos todo se vuelve un conflito.

Comment: @the-breaker como ves el codigo, esta muy mal

Comment: ya te dieron la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes convertir cada resultado usando [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString) y pasándole la localización para España usando `es`:

```js
function calculaPorcentajes(numero){
  document.getElementById("porcent4").value = (Math.floor(numero*4)/100).toLocaleString('es');
  document.getElementById("porcent6").value = (Math.floor(numero*6)/100).toLocaleString('es');
  document.getElementById("porcent8").value = (Math.floor(numero*8)/100).toLocaleString('es');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    
Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad"  onKeyUp="calculaPorcentajes(this.value)"><br><br>
4%: <input type="text" name="porcent4" id="porcent4"><br><br>
6%: <input type="text" name="porcent6" id="porcent6"><br><br>
8%: <input type="text" name="porcent8" id="porcent8">    
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que hace `toLocateString` es formatear el número acorde a la localización.

Por ejemplo, acá en Perú no nos gustan los puntos, preferimos las comas. Le cambias la localización a `es-PE` y listo:

```js
function calculaPorcentajes(numero){
  document.getElementById("porcent4").value = (Math.floor(numero*4)/100).toLocaleString('es-PE');
  document.getElementById("porcent6").value = (Math.floor(numero*6)/100).toLocaleString('es-PE');
  document.getElementById("porcent8").value = (Math.floor(numero*8)/100).toLocaleString('es-PE');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    
Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad"  onKeyUp="calculaPorcentajes(this.value)"><br><br>
4%: <input type="text" name="porcent4" id="porcent4"><br><br>
6%: <input type="text" name="porcent6" id="porcent6"><br><br>
8%: <input type="text" name="porcent8" id="porcent8">    
</body>
</html>
```

¿Difentes formatos para cada número? No hay problema, creamos una función que reciba el tipo de localización:

```js
function formateaNumero(number, locale) {
  return number.toLocaleString(locale)
}

function calculaPorcentajes(numero){
  document.getElementById("porcent4").value = formateaNumero(Math.floor(numero*4)/100, 'es-PE');
  document.getElementById("porcent6").value = formateaNumero(Math.floor(numero*6)/100, 'es');
  document.getElementById("porcent8").value = formateaNumero(Math.floor(numero*8)/100, 'fr');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    
Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad"  onKeyUp="calculaPorcentajes(this.value)"><br><br>
4%: <input type="text" name="porcent4" id="porcent4"><br><br>
6%: <input type="text" name="porcent6" id="porcent6"><br><br>
8%: <input type="text" name="porcent8" id="porcent8">    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo eres un duro en eso genial, ahora ya entiendo un poco todo voy a buscar como es el formato de colombia.

Amigo donde dice cantidad como hago para formatear ese input?

Comment: ayuda mi amigo :8

Comment: @AlvaroMejia, ¿aun quieres formatear ese input? venga te ayudo pero antes decide que formato quieres usar.

Comment: @the-breaker si amigo, el formato  .toLocaleString('es');  ese fue el que me sirvio amigo.

Comment: @AlvaroMejia, te pregunto por el input de entrada

Comment: Si, el input que se donde se ingresa la cantidad.

Comment: @the-breaker amigo muchas gracias que pena molestarte tanto, soy muy novato en esto.

Answer (score 2):

Acotando a la respuesta de César, para dar formato también al input de entrada y que quede como quieres tendrás que antes que quitar los puntos para reutilizar el numero de la siguiente forma:

```js
function formateaNumero(number, locale) {
  return number.toLocaleString(locale)
}

function calculaPorcentajes(numero){
  //quitar los puntos para reutilizar el numero
  numero=(numero+"").split(".").join("");
  document.getElementById("porcent4").value = formateaNumero(Math.floor(numero*4)/100, 'es-PE');
  document.getElementById("porcent6").value = formateaNumero(Math.floor(numero*6)/100, 'es');
  document.getElementById("porcent8").value = formateaNumero(Math.floor(numero*8)/100, 'fr');
  return formateaNumero(numero*1,'es');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>    
Cantidad: <input type="text" name="cantidad"  onKeyUp="this.value=calculaPorcentajes(this.value)"><br><br>
4%: <input type="text" name="porcent4" id="porcent4"><br><br>
6%: <input type="text" name="porcent6" id="porcent6"><br><br>
8%: <input type="text" name="porcent8" id="porcent8">    
</body>
</html>
```

En resumen se recupera el numero, se le quita los puntos, se lo procesa y se envía al input ya con formato. Ya con esto queda identico a la imagen. Saludos.

Comment: @AlvaroMejia, de nada pero no hace falta que le quites la respuesta aceptada a César, también aporto mucho. Saludos.

Comment: @AlvaroMejia ¿un valor mínimo? o un tamaño mínimo de dígitos?

Comment: @AlvaroMejia debajo de `numero=(numero+"").split(".").join("");` pon `if(numero*1<800000) numero=800000; if(numero*1>1000000000) numero=1000000000;` y eso es todo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95788/discussion-between-the-breaker-and-alvaro-mejia).

Comment: Alguien sabe como puedo hacer si ingresan  un valor menor : 
el primer input sume.

Me explico  (si ingresa 400.000 que en el primer input le sume 200.000) pero si (ingresa  un valor mayor a 400.000 no sume nada)